# Is the jQuery mobile the best UI framework to integrate with PhoneGap? Or should I use Ionic?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, ionic-framework

I wanna to use PhoneGap to starting an enterprise application, but don't know which of all the mobile UI frameworks is the best to integrate with the project?

i'm new to PhoneGap.

Comment: jQuery Mobile is a terrible mess with a bunch of weird errors (such as broken scrolling on iOS due to its CSS file) and I regret using it. We should have just gone with Ionic....

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, Ionic is the best in your opinion?

Comment: I have not used it, but i've heard great things about it from someone who did. The downside is that one has to learn AngularJS for it as it relies on Angular. However, I can guarantee you that jQuery Mobile is a buggy mess, I worked with that and would hopefully never again.

Comment: From experience, I had a bad time with Jquery mobile. It's bloated and it just did not really do it form me as a mobile framework. Halfway through a project I switched to Kendo UI because it was more of a MVC framework, enabling a DRY workflow out-of-the-box. Also when testing on older mobile devices, JQuery mobile became like the Titanic. I have had my eye on Ionic since it appeared on the scene a bit over a year ago. The fact that Ionic uses AngularJS is the biggest reason why I'm now using it to make hybrid apps. I'm putting my money on Ionic.

Comment: http://sourcefreeze.com/best-mobile-ui-frameworks-using-html5-css-and-js/

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you want to choose between jQuery Mobile and Ionic Framework I would advise you to pick Ionic. This will, of course, depend on your knowledge and preferences.

1. First jQuery Mobile is not "a buggy mess", @EpicPandaForce don't know what his talking about. If you don't believe me take a look at my jQuery Mobile support score here at SO: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-mobile/topusers. If anyone knows how jQuery Mobile works it's me. This does not mean jQuery Mobile is better; it simply has its place in this world and mobile ecosystem
2. jQuery Mobile was not updated in last two years, even then it wasn't the fastest solution for mobile development. Version 1.5 will come out soon, and it will bring jQuery UI integration. jQuery Mobile possibilities will skyrocket.
3. Ionic is under constant development, and I would agree it's production ready at this point. Though even now it lacks 3rd party support jQuery Mobile has.
4. The Ionic is faster than jQuery Mobile though still not fully native like. You should consider that jQuery Mobile was not created as a fully hybrid mobile framework. It is merely a mobile desktop framework, never optimized for a pure mobile run.
5. Though Ionic has an AngularJS backend, it's not as tight as jQuery/jQuery Mobile.
6. Currently, Ionic has a much better community. It is not as large as jQuery Mobile community, but people are much more active and prepared to help.
7. Ionic developers actively communicate with the community (Ionic Forum, even here at SO). jQuery Mobile developers can be only found at an IRC channel, and you may count yourself lucky if they respond.
8. jQuery Mobile is easier to develop with, and Ionic is still missing some features jQuery Mobile has. For example various page (view) transitions, and you can easily create your own. Still, unless you're careful, your jQuery Mobile application can become a slow mess of code.
9. jQuery Mobile can be tough if you don't carefully read framework documentation. For example, you should never use document ready with jQuery Mobile. A lot of people don't understand or know this. Just like Ionic has View events jQuery Mobile has page events (to be used instead of document ready).
10. jQuery Mobile has a MUCH better theme(s) selection
11. jQuery Mobile almost killed PhoneGap all together. Currently, jQuery Mobile 1.4 is fast/usable enough.
12. Everything said Ionic is still better and faster than jQuery Mobile.
13. Ionic is currently best available hybrid mobile framework. If you don't like this statement then consider it mostly used framework.

## Conclusion

- If you have a previous jQuery knowledge and you don't have time to learn AngularJS stick with jQuery Mobile.
- In any other case choose Ionic.